# parse live query cocoapods and Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cocoapods, xcode8

I had a working project on Xcode 8.2.1 and swift 3. I wanted to add parse live query so I used cocoa pods to add the frame work. When I opened the workspace it said the syntax needed to be updated. Now I have over 500 errors in my app. Any ideas why this might have happened or how can I install the pod without this. Please ask for further info I'm not sure what would be useful here. 
Thanks!

Comment: Parse is shutting down on January 28 (18 days). Sure you want to start using it?

Comment: Im using the parse server

Comment: Ok good. just making sure

Comment: Does one of the errors reference one of your pods and say something about using a Legacy Swift version? I had this problem once and had to explicitly declare that the pod was using a Legacy version of swift (which I did by just clicking on that error and changing it from `undetermined` to `YES`

Comment: None of the errors say anything about legacy, most are things like use of undeclared..., expected ..., and basic small errors like that. There doesnt seem to be anything wrong when looking at them though and there is so many

Comment: I think the problem may have something to do with bolts

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the ParseLiveQuery version is out of date.

Try:

1) make sure your Podfile has `pod 'ParseLiveQuery', '2.0.0'` (latest version as of Apr. 2017)

2) run `pod repo update` then `pod install`

3) clean and rebuild your swift project